# javax.xml.xpath jar/src available?

Tags: java, android, xpath

does anybody know where i can download the src code or even a lib jar file of this package?

the reason i ask is because i wish to use xpath on android devices that are lower than android 2.2

Android 2.2 is the only API that supports and uses the xpath package which is very strange as xpath has been in J2SE for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

These are present in rt.jar from the JRE/lib. But you're not supposed to use those on Android.

See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=458 and http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=515 for a workaround

> The Android system provides its own
>   equivalent, so it is inappropriate to
>   try to use rt.jar as part of an
>   Android application.